# I need a function returning a page that includes items in plsql-apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a working function that redirects to a page. It has one of 3 outcomes, based on the employee code that was filled in a number field.

1 If the number is of an employee that is not a manager it redirects to a page for employees (page 4)
2 If the number is of an employee that is a manager it redirects to a page for managers (page 10)
3 If the number is not of any employee, it throws an error

Now this formula works and does what it needs to do, however there is one issue. The page that is called needs the employee number that was filled in as well to fill the content. How can I get that done?

Here is the entire code I have:

```
return f_areyouaboss(:MEDEWERKERCODE);
```

That is in the pl/sql function body in the apex app builder

```
return number
as
v_pagenumber number(1);
Begin
Declare
    cursor c_medewerkers(v_mnr number) is
        select MNR, CHEF
        from medewerkers;
    c_medewerkers_rec    c_medewerkers%rowtype;
    v_chef               number(1);
    v_loonslaaf          number(1);
    v_klaar              number(1);
    v_mnrtest            number(4);
Begin
    v_mnrtest := v_mnrinput;
    v_chef := 0;
    v_loonslaaf := 0;
    v_klaar := 0;
    open c_medewerkers(v_mnrtest);
        while v_klaar = 0 loop
            fetch c_medewerkers into c_medewerkers_rec;
            if (c_medewerkers%NOTFOUND) then
                v_klaar :=1;
            elsif (c_medewerkers_rec.chef = v_mnrtest) then
                return 4;
                v_klaar :=1;
            elsif (c_medewerkers_rec.mnr = v_mnrtest) then
                v_loonslaaf := 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
        if (v_loonslaaf = 1) then
            return 10;
        elsif (v_chef = 0) then
            raise_application_error(-20096,'Medewerker bestaat niet');
        end if;
    close c_medewerkers;
END;
END;
```

Due to restrictions I can only use PL/SQL and Apex, not javascript

Comment: What is implementing the actual redirect?  Is there a call to `apex_util.redirect_url` somewhere that takes the return value from this function as the page to redirect to?  If so, you'd normally just pass the employee number on the URL you construct to redirect to.  If you really wanted to, you could have an apex_util.set_session_state call to set the parameter value outside the URL but I wouldn't advise that generally.

Comment: Lars, where is this function run ? Is it on page submit ?

Comment: it works on oracle App builder, I have managed to fix it by creating an application item which stores the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by creating an application item in the Apex app builder which stores the value I need. Additionally the pages that need this value now have a dynamic action that triggers on the loading of the page that retrieves the value. It's a workaround, but it works.